# Как добавить запрос для уже существующего запроса SQL?

Tags: php, sql, yii2

Всем привет, покажу на примере:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
```

Можно ли для `$sql` добавить ещё какой нибудь запрос

```
if(!empty($id)) {
 $sql = "WHERE `id` = $id";
}
```

Например, такой:

```
$data = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
```

Comment: Мне именно нужно чтобы работало с ``createCommand``. Если кто знает отпишитесь пожалуйста :)

Comment: ```$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 1=1";``` и соответственно ```$sql .= " AND `id` = $id";```. *добавить ещё какой нибудь запрос* - это добавить не запрос, а условие в него.

Comment: просто бывает что иногда ``id`` null и выводить всё равно нужно, а что можно в таком случае делать?

Comment: o_O ```$sql .= " AND (id = $id OR id IS NULL)";```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$where = '';
if(!empty($id)) {
  $where .= "WHERE `id` = $id;
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` $where";
```

Нашел ответ тут: https://qna.habr.com/q/434162